# Is there a way to force Rust to let me use a possibly moved value?

Tags: rust

Have I just forgotten how borrows and moves work?

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3]; // I have some uncopyable value

if false {
    let t = v; // I might do something that consumes it
}

println!("{:?}", v); // in some condition, I know for sure that I didn't consume it
```

Can I somehow use an `unsafe` clause to tell the compiler to trust me?

Any solution must have no runtime overhead.

Comment: Stuff it in an option?

Comment: @CodesInChaos That would still require runtime overhead. If I were programming in c++, I wouldn't have to sacrifice performance for flexibility. Rust claims that it never sacrifices performance from c++ and that I can just wrap unsafe code to deal with these scenarios.

Comment: Even in C++ this would be tricky, since you need to ensure that the destructor doesn't run when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: I now realize that in c++, when a move is done on a vector, it goes through the same nullification that would be setting it equal to an empty vector in rust.

Comment: @Evan That's one thing that leads to the possibility of Rust being *faster* than C++. Since Rust doesn't *have* to fill in a zero-value, it can conceptually do fewer operations. As @CodesInChaos shows, you can choose that path by replacing the value with an empty `Vec`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler won't let you access a variable you may have moved the value out of, even in unsafe code.

Some workarounds:

- Wrap it in an `Option`. You can then move the data out using the `take` method, leaving a `None` value behind.

  This is the approach I recommend for local variables.
- Replace the original vector by an empty vector. This is cheap, since empty vectors don't allocate.

  ```
  let t = std::mem::replace(&mut v, Vec::new());
  ```

  This is the closest equivalent to C++ moving, which is described as:

  > Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be
  >   placed in a valid but unspecified state.
- Wrap it in `ManuallyDrop` (this is safer than `mem::forget` because it doesn't drop the value when a panic happens). Drop it manually at the end on the path where it's still initialized. Use deref to access it while it is still valid. `ptr::read` to copy the value out, treating the original location as invalid/uninitialized.

  This shouldn't have any runtime overhead, but I *strongly* recommend not using this on local variables. It's just not worth the complexity and risks.

  ```
  use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;
  use std::ptr;

  fn main() {
      let flag = //...;
      unsafe {
          let mut v = ManuallyDrop::new(vec![1, 2, 3]); // I have some uncopyable value

          if flag {
              let t = ptr::read(&*v); // I might do something that consumes it
              // don't touch *v from now on
              println!("{:?}", t);
          }

          if !flag {
              println!("{:?}", *v); // in some condition, I know for sure that I didn't consume it
              ManuallyDrop::drop(&mut v);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4775bf415675617158813bc26d54abcd&version=stable)

Answer (score 5):

No.

> I know for sure that I didn't consume it

Just because you didn't write any code that didn't consume it doesn't mean that it wasn't consumed. [Ownership and conditionally executed code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28948716/155423) discusses the mechanics of type- and stack-based *drop flags* further, but conceptually your code is:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];

if false {
    let _t = v;
    drop(_t);
} else {
    drop(v);
}

println!("{:?}", v);
```

Once the conditional is over, your value is as good as gone. (implementation-wise, the [drops *do* happen at the end of the function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4d65daafe4dc9e71ee98f2b1c48e015a&version=stable), but the semantics don't express that).

> in some condition

That condition would be the `else` block of your `if` statement:

```
if false {
    let _t = v;
} else {
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Comment: But the location where there is only a chance of consumption might not always be as simple as an if (it might be a loop). A better question would be, "can you prove that there will always be some mathematical equivalent of an else statement".

Comment: @Evan Moving a value out of a variable in a loop won't compile, since the variable will be invalid starting from the second iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `mem::replace`, if you want to imitate C++ move semantics.

```
use std::mem;

let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3]; // I have some uncopyable value

if false {
    let t = mem::replace(&mut v, vec![]); // I might do something that consumes it
}

println!("{:?}", v);
```

`vec![]` is guarantied to not allocate memory, so there's no runtime overhead. In the general case you will need some "zero" value for your uncopiable type just like in C++. If you can't come up with "zero" value, you can always use `Option` as CodesInChaos answer suggests.

Comment: "no runtime overhead" is overstating it a bit. [`mem::replace` does more work than `ManuallyDrop` and less than `Option`, by instruction count](https://godbolt.org/g/JU23TD), although `Option` would likely be further optimized in real-life code.

Comment: @trentcl, no runtime overhead as compared to C++ implementation.

Comment: I'd expect C++ to do something similar to `ManuallyDrop`, but I admit I don't understand how move semantics work in that language.